# Adding East Sussex ArcGIS Online Services to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server

Looking for info on how to add web mapping services from the East Sussex  of ARGIS Tithe Map  Resources website to QGIS. I've tried nearly a five different things online and still can't get results. I am asking here but decided to attempt this route for fear that it was impossible (permissions issues, etc.). Link to data I want to add is posted below:

https://escc.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=94d9d72603034a85bb68bce793fb5a59

or here :

Answer (score 1):

The rest end point behind the AGOL service is https://maps1.eastsussex.gov.uk/server/rest/services/. The end point your are looking for is https://maps1.eastsussex.gov.uk/server/rest/services/TitheMaps/MapServer

You can add this in QGIS using Layer/Add Layer/ArcGIS Map Server and add the above rest end point. Tested and working using 3.12.1

Comment: How did you work out what the rest end point is from an online map like this?

Comment: View the AGOL service in a web browser and use Developer Tools to view network traffic. You will see something like https://maps1.eastsussex.gov.uk/server/rest/services/OsBase/MapServer/tile/0/128/169 and you can deduce the end point from there.